# Why is mdtool failing to compile after I upgraded to latest version of MonoDevelop/MonoTouch/XCode?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop, mdtool

I'm using mdtool to build my MonoTouch apps. However, since upgrading today to MonoTouch 3.2.5, MonoDevelop 2.4.2, XCode 4 and Snow Leopard, mdtool now fails to build my app.

The app seems to build OK in MonoDevelop. But I use mdtool in my build scripts.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Last lines of log (I'm calling it from xbuild) are:

> /var/folders/tW/tWXQsmWiGQSFrBhErcI2wE+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp4233680e.tmp: line 1:  1119 Abort trap              /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/mdtool build ../MyProject.sln -p:"MyProject.Iphone" -c:"AdHoc|iPhone"
>   /Users/default/Projects/MyProject/Build/Build.xml: error : Command '/Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/mdtool build ../MyProject.sln -p:"MyProject.Iphone" -c:"AdHoc|iPhone"' exited with code: 134.

**Update**

The problem might be in this area:

> Updating application manifest
>   2011-03-11 20:35:32.630 mono[2134:60f] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x4146e20 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
>   2011-03-11 20:35:32.633 mono[2134:60f] +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xa02d13ec
>   2011-03-11 20:35:32.634 mono[2134:60f] *** _*NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x4144ec0 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
>   Stacktrace:
>     at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoDevelop.IPhone.IPhoneFramework.SendMessage (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>
>     at MonoDevelop.IPhone.IPhoneFramework.GetDTSettings () <0x001f9>
>     at MonoDevelop.IPhone.IPhoneBuildExtension/c*_AnonStorey8.<>m__4 (MonoDevelop.MacDev.Plist.PlistDocument) <0x0087b>

I haven't made any changes to the code since updating, though - and it all worked previously.

Comment: Are you using the preview of OS X 10.7 (Lion)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might want to try #monodevelop on IRC.

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in git master and the 2.4 branch. The next release should contain the fix.